# How to Ensure outsourced programmers don't maliciously use your server?

Tags: security, backend

I have outsourced the programming of an iPhone app.

The programmer has requested access to a server to uploaded data from the app which is a necessary part of our app.

However I have never met the programmer.

I don't have any programming skills, and wouldn't know what he has uploaded to the server.

So therefore,

Do you know of any solutions to my issue of ensuring that the server is only used for the purpose of our app, and not for running any other code.

I intend on using amazon servers, but could use another option depending on the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy "magic bullet" - You will need to trust *someone* whatever you do.

Either you will need to trust your developer to use the server correctly. Or you will need to trust an experienced sysadmin to set up the server properly and give defined access rights to other users.

In my experience, it is unlikely that a developer you hire will use your server for malicious purposes. However it is quite likely that either:

- They will use the server for some other, non-malicious uses on the grounds that "no-one will notice" (e.g. transferring a few files). Probably not a big issue as long as they are sensible.
- They will make a mistake with config / security that will allow others to gain unauthorised access. This could be a big problem - you could find your server hijacked and your customer data compromised.

Basically it all comes down to trust, your tolerance for risk, and how much you are willing to pay an expert to run this stuff for you.